# Mongoose connection does not contain models and collections

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, serverless

I have a problem with my Mongoose connections and i don't understand how I can fix it because it looks like it happens randomly

I have a Serverless API that I run offline. I use "serverless-middleware-plugin" to connect and disconnect from my DB

My connect middleware looks like that :

```js
export const handler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        if(mongoose.connections[0].readyState == 1) return Promise.resolve();
        return await mongoose.connect(
            mongoURI,{ 
                useCreateIndex: true,
                useNewUrlParser: true, 
                useUnifiedTopology: true,  
                useFindAndModify: false
            }
        )
    } catch (error) {
        context.end();
        return response({
            statusCode: 500,
            body: error.toString()
        });
    }   
};
```

And my response middle (which disconnect mongoose after the execution of my function) looks like that :

```js
export const handler = async (event, context) => {
    if(mongoose.connections[0].readyState == 1)  await mongoose.disconnect()
    const { statusCode, body } = context.prev;
    return response({
        statusCode: (statusCode || 500) ? statusCode : 500,
        body: statusCode? body: context.prev.toString()
    });
};
```

If I log my `mongoose.connections[0]` after the mongoose.connect() in my connect middleware, it should contains models and collections of my DB base, like that :

```js
   models: {
     Account: Model { Account },
     Announces: Model { Announces }
   },
   modelSchemas: {
     Account: [Schema],
     Announces: [Schema]
   },
   collections: {
    Account: NativeCollection {
     collection: [Collection],
     Promise: [Function: Promise],
     modelName: 'Account',,
     name: 'Account',
     collectionName: 'Account',
    },
    Announces: NativeCollection {
     collection: [Collection],
     Promise: [Function: Promise],
     modelName: 'Announces',
     name: 'Announces',
     collectionName: 'Announces'
   }
}
```

But rarely, it does not contains anything in models or collections object, but the connection readyState is indeed equal to 1. And it result in a timeout request like `` Operation `Account.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms ``

If you have any ideas why this is happening, I'm all ears

If you need more informations about my API, Serverless configuration, or schemas configurations, don't hesitate to ask

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you add the code where you have the mongoose.connect or mongoose.createConnection call?

Comment: it's already in the post, it's the first code window